# Way to connect Clojurescript Repl to running node process

Tags: node.js, debugging, clojurescript

I was wondering if there is a way to connect a cljs repl to a nodejs process that I already have running, that is say in debug mode and stopped at a breakpoint.

So I know there is https://github.com/bodil/cljs-noderepl, and I have this running fine, but it starts up a 'sandboxed environment' as it says in the documentation.  I'd like it to connect to a node process of my choosing (e.g. node debug my_project.js).

I can use the normal node debugger, but that's plain old JS, not CLJS.

I also looked into nRepl, but that doesn't seem to be the solution.

Is what I'm asking for possible at the moment, or can I only do this type of repl in a browser environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I don't think node has a way to communicate with a running enviroment. nREPL actually is a step there as it will listen in a nodejs app and let clients send it code, but I haven't seen a nREPL server for node.js clojurescript.

The best I've gotten is https://plus.google.com/112151928607622120183/posts/fNr5h8BgLEp

Comment: You can use NodeJS to run a CLJS REPL but not sure if that answers your question: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start#running-clojurescript-on-nodejs